# php access db class from inside a function

Tags: php, class, function, pdo

My database class works perfectly and I call it like this `$db = new Database('user', 'pass', 'db', 'host');`. I top of my script I am defining this database, but later in the script I am trying to use the connection inside a function, but it seems to that the `$db` is not global, so my function can't access it. I have the possibility to create a new database class connection inside every function in my script, but I really would like to access the `$db` as a global access point.

Here is some code:

```
 require_once('database_class.php');

 $db = new Database('user', 'pass', 'db', 'host');



 // I can reach the $db here and make the $db->PDO->'statement'();



 function userExists($user) {

     $bool = false;

     // But in here I can't access $db...
     $query = $db->PDO->query('SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = "$user"');

     $result = $query->fetch();

     if ($result) {

         // User exists
         $bool = true;

     }

     return $bool;

 }
```

Comment: Research about Singleton pattern. It's mostly used for purposes such as yours.

Comment: Not really an "answer" but what I mostly do is make Class methods (functions) that just open the connection, do the query, close the connection and then handle and return the data. Might be some specialist that says it's better to leave the connection open, but I never noticed a performance impact by doing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put global $db at the beginning of the function like so:

```
 function userExists($user) {
      global $db;

     // Rest of code here
```

Variables within functions only exist locally by default in PHP. To use a variable declared outside of a function which is not passed as an argument (e.g $user) you need to use a global variable as shown above.

Comment: But when the variable is defined outside the function, is it automatiaclly 'global', or how?

Comment: Either pass it as a function argument or declare the variable as global.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted when it's defined outside of the function it's global, but the scope is different inside of the function. By adding the keyword `global` you're adding that variable to your function scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just modify your functions to take the $db var as an argument.  e.g. :

```
function userExists($user, $db) {
    ...
}
```

Objects are passed by reference by default (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)) so you won't be inadvertently making copies of the $db object with each call.

Comment: It would have a long way to travel, because the function is called by a function that's called by a function... But yeah.. that might actually be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I use classes for connections and queries too. But it would help that you define already in your class the variables needed for connection, so you don't have to repeat them in every page of code.
and maybe this? use the db as an argument.

function userExists($user, $db) { //codecodecode }